# Provider does not update a variable while fetching data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

Firstly, I have a login screen and I want to change button with `CircularProgressIndicator`  when button is clicked. I am using Provider to handle state management. Here is my Provider class.

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
bool _loading = false;
bool get loading => _loading;
UserViewModel? user;
bool isLoggedOut = false;
TokenRequestModel tokenRequestModel = TokenRequestModel(
  username: '', password: '', environment: '', deviceToken: '');

login(TokenRequestModel requestModel) async {
  _loading = true;
  user = await UserService().login(requestModel);
  _loading = false;

  notifyListeners();
 }

}
```

I change loading value between my Api call. Then I want to catch it in my login screen to change widget. With that way I prevent button clicked multiple times and my login screen looks like this.

```
Column(
              children: [
                //textfield widgets

                context.watch<UserProvider>().loading == false
                    ? button(context, userProvider)
                    : Container(
                        height: 35.h,
                        width: 280.w,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: blueLogo),
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
              ],
            ),
```

I have tried multiple methods like Consumer, `userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);` but nothing happens. What am I missing or what is the mistake of my method to handle state management? Would you help me to find right way to do? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you are notifying listeners when `_loading` has gone back to being `false` again, but you never notified them when it turned `true`!

Try this, in your `provider` file:

```
class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
bool _loading = false;
bool get loading => _loading;
UserViewModel? user;
bool isLoggedOut = false;
TokenRequestModel tokenRequestModel = TokenRequestModel(
  username: '', password: '', environment: '', deviceToken: '');

login(TokenRequestModel requestModel) async {
  _loading = true;
  notifyListeners();  // <- The crucial line, right here!

  user = await UserService().login(requestModel);
  _loading = false;
  notifyListeners();
 }

}
```

I noticed you had used `with ChangeNotifier` instead of `extends ChangeNotifier`... but I don't know what that does! I always use `extends ChangeNotifier` and that works for me.

Comment: Provider's document has with ChangeNotifier, thats why I used that. I think api returns really fast, that is why UI cant change quickly. I understand that when I added second notifyListeners(). There is nothing wrong but api returns fast :) Thanks

Comment: Does it? I learned Flutter in the LondonAppBrewery bootcamp course (with Angela Yu) and she used `extends ChangeNotifier`... Anyway, if you want to really check the funtionality, you can always add a second delay, with `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));` or something, after the `.login()` line! Then you'll see for sure if it spins or not. 

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example Provider document uses with ChangeNotifier but it does not effect with or extends in my case. Thanks for advice btw